# International Drupal 6 Menu

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am new to Drupal (3 weeks) so if I am not clear just ask and I'll clarify.

I have an English Drupal 6 site. The Primary Links menu has 4 items. A-B-C-D. They all work etc. Now we have added several language domains and translated content through translation dashboard etc.

Now in the menu for international users we want the Menu to be A-Z-B-D.

So if a user goes to mydomain.com they see A-B-C-D. If they goto mydomain.com/fr they see A-Z-B-D.

What we ended up doing was making menu item C visible to English only. We then added 1 menu item (Z) for the different languages and translated the menu text. The menu shows properly for each domain.

So what's the problem?....2 things.

1. The menu links, regardless of domain, are in English. What I mean is that the menu text may be in French but when you hover the mouse over the link the target url displayed (lower left) is still in English.
2. We could correct #1 by adding a whole lotta menu items, setting the menu link title to the text for that language, and making display language rules for all of them.....seems like a cluttered mess just waiting for an opportunity....

So what I would like is ideas on how to have the fewest number of menu items, yet have complete translations including the menu link titles.

TIA
JB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **not** mix menus with different languages.

Create new menu for each language and place then in the same region but define language per menu.